# Email signature gets messed up on reply

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, signature

I have a problem with my email signature. It gets messed up when replying in Outlook.

What is happening: When I send an email with the signature from Outlook 2016 (on Mac) to Outlook 2007 (on Windows) it looks good. When replying to that email it still looks good. When replying to that email the signature gets messed up. Screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUabZ.png)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
/* Client-specific Styles */

#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
body {
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font,     .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */
#backgroundTable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
}
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
.image_fix {
    display: block;
}
p {
    margin: 0px 0px !important;
}
table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

 /*##############################################*/
 /*IPHONE STYLES*/
 /*##############################################*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    table {
    position: relative;
}

table[class="fluid-table"], td[class="fluid-cell"]{
    width: 100% !important;
}

}
</style>

</head>


<body>
<div class="block"> 

    <!-- Start of name, function title and logo -->

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                <span style="text-align: left; color: #9C1C27;font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold">Voornaam en Achternaam</span><br/>
                <span style="text-align: left; color: #B5987F; font-weight: normal; font-style:italic; font-size: 14px;">Functie titel</span><br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/"><img src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/logo.png" nosend="1" border="0" style="width:179px; height:111px; padding: 10px 0 5px 0;"  alt="De Leeuw Hides logo" title="De Leeuw Hides logo" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of name, function and logo -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" class="fluid-table">
          <tr>

            <!-- Start of first column --> 

            <td><table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td width="175" style=" border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                        <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Nijmegen</strong><br/>
                        Lindenhoutseweg 69<br/>
                        6545 AH Nijmegen <br/>
                        The Netherlands
                    </td>   
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>

              <!-- End of first column --> 


              <!-- Start of second column -->

              <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td width="175" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                        <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Winterswijk</strong><br/>
                        Industrieweg 2a<br/>
                        7102 DZ Winterswijk<br/>
                        The Netherlands
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <!-- End of second column --> 



              <!-- Start of third column -->

              <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="175" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                            <a href="tel:0031-024-3775233" style="color:#B5987F;">T:0031-024-3775233</a> <br/>
                            <span style="text-decoration:none">F: 0031-024-3779316</span> <br/>
                            <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="mailto:sales@deleeuwhides.nl"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">sales@deleeuwhides.nl</span></a><br/>
                            <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">www.deleeuwhides.com</span></a>
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

              <!-- End of third column -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


        <!-- Start of branding identity elements -->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"  class="fluid-table">
           <tr>
                <td style="height:3px; width:100%; background-color:#B5987F;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"class="fluid-table">
           <tr>
                <td style="height:2px; width:100%; background-color:#fff;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="fluid-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" style="height:30px; width:100%; background-color:#9C1C27;"><center><img style="display:block;" src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/slogan-footer.png" alt="slogan"></center>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
        <!-- End of branding identity elements-->

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I sent your message to me from http://putsmail.com to my Outlook address, replied to my gmail and then replied back to my Outlook and got this:

[image]

When I replied back to gmail, it looked fine.

My suggestion is to add `valign="top"` to your tr and td cells in the table in question. This will force the table cells to align.

`

```
        <!-- Start of first column --> 

        <td valign="top">
          <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>

              <tr valign="top">
                <td valign="top" width="175" style=" border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                    <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Nijmegen</strong><br/>
                    Lindenhoutseweg 69<br/>
                    6545 AH Nijmegen <br/>
                    The Netherlands
                </td>   
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of first column --> 


          <!-- Start of second column -->

          <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>

              <tr valign="top">
                <td valign="top" width="175" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                    <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Winterswijk</strong><br/>
                    Industrieweg 2a<br/>
                    7102 DZ Winterswijk<br/>
                    The Netherlands
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of second column --> 



          <!-- Start of third column -->

          <table width="175" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table">
            <tbody>
              <tr valign="top">
                 <td valign="top" width="175" style="border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;" border="0">
                        <a href="tel:0031-024-3775233" style="color:#B5987F;">T:0031-024-3775233</a> <br/>
                        <span style="text-decoration:none">F: 0031-024-3779316</span> <br/>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="mailto:sales@deleeuwhides.nl"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">sales@deleeuwhides.nl</span></a><br/>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">www.deleeuwhides.com</span></a>
                    </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- End of third column -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- Start of branding identity elements -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"  class="fluid-table">
       <tr>
            <td style="height:3px; width:100%; background-color:#B5987F;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"class="fluid-table">
       <tr>
            <td style="height:2px; width:100%; background-color:#fff;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="fluid-table">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height:30px; width:100%; background-color:#9C1C27;"><center><img style="display:block;" src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/slogan-footer.png" alt="slogan"></center>
                    </td>
               </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- End of branding identity elements-->

  </td>
</tr>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I first removed all align attributes which helped to put the columns next to each other. I then removed all the tables and made one "wrapper" table with a table nested in to this wrapper table which contains everything. Hope I'm describing this clearly, lol. Anyway this solved all my problems!

This is my code for anyone who is interested or has the same problems I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
/* Client-specific Styles */

#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
body {
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%;
} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */
#backgroundTable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
}
img {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
.image_fix {
    display: block;
}
p {
    margin: 0px 0px !important;
}

table td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

/*##############################################*/
 /*IPHONE STYLES*/
 /*##############################################*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
table {
    position: relative;
}

table[class="fluid-table"], td[class="fluid-cell"]{
    width: 100% !important;
}

}
</style>

</head>


<body>
<div class="block"> 

    <!-- Start of wrapper table -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" class="fluid-table">

    <!-- Start of name, function title and logo -->
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:3px; outline:none; text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-size:14px; text-align:left; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
                    <strong style="color: #9C1C27;font-size: 15px;">Voornaam en Achternaam</strong><br/>
                    <em style="color: #B5987F; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px;">Functie titel</em><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <a href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/"><img src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/logo.png" nosend="1" border="0" style="display:block; width:179px; height:111px;"  alt="De Leeuw Hides logo" title="De Leeuw Hides logo" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>   
    <!-- End of name, function and logo -->


                <!-- Contact info and Start of first column --> 
                      <tr>
                        <td width="200" style="padding-bottom:3px; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px;  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
                            <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Nijmegen</strong><br/>
                            Lindenhoutseweg 69<br/>
                            6545 AH Nijmegen <br/>
                            The Netherlands
                        </td>   
                  <!-- End of first column --> 


                  <!-- Start of second column -->
                        <td width="200" style="padding-bottom:3px; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px;  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
                        <strong style="color:#9C1C27;">Location Winterswijk</strong><br/>
                            Industrieweg 2a<br/>
                            7102 DZ Winterswijk<br/>
                            The Netherlands
                        </td>
                    <!-- End of second column --> 

                  <!-- Start of third column -->
                         <td width="200" style="padding-bottom:3px; text-decoration:none; color:#B5987F; font-size:14px; font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
                                <a href="tel:0031-024-3775233" style="color:#B5987F;">T:0031-024-3775233</a> <br/>
                                <span style="text-decoration:none">F: 0031-024-3779316</span> <br/>
                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="mailto:sales@deleeuwhides.nl"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">sales@deleeuwhides.nl</span></a><br/>
                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;" href="http://www.deleeuwhides.com"><span style="text-decoration:none; color:#9C1C27;">www.deleeuwhides.com</span></a>
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
           <!-- End of third column and contact info -->


            <!-- Start of branding identity elements -->

               <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#B5987F" style="height:3px; width:100%;"></td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="height:3px; width:100%;"></td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#9C1C27" style="height:30px; width:100%;">
                                <center>
                                    <img style="display:block;"src="http://www.deleeuwhides.com/img/slogan-footer.png" alt="slogan" />
                                </center>
                            </td>
                       </tr>

            <!--    End of branding identity elements -->

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- end of wrapper table -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welll, as they say: "Email is hard".

In general, it is a good practice to inline the CSS styles when doing stuff for emails. I use [this tool](https://putsmail.com/inliner) from Litmus, and they also have [a pretty good article](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1) about the pitfalls of developing HTML content that looks good for emails (gmail specifically).

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers! Yes email is really, really hard. The problem isn't Gmail however. I tested that and it's working so far as I can see. 
The problem is Outlook and I think specifically Outlook 2007. It's so weird that the problem occurs only after the third reply. I will definitely try the valign top thing and report back.

Comment: I know it's not gmail. I simply wanted to report back what I did. Outlook is very notorious for this type of behavior and I wanted to see if it modified the code at all. I lacked Outlook Mac for testing, which is why I used putsmail to send, which does not edit the code at all.

Comment: Thanks again. Tested it with valign=top which didn't make a difference. I then tested it with all the non-inline css code stripped and that also didn't work.

Also really weird is that the latest reply doesn't show this problem. It's always the ones before that. 

And I tested it also with Gmail like you did and got the same results. It really seems to be an Outlook 2007 problem. I can't wrap my mind around why it only happens on the reply. It looks fine when you send it, then when you reply the original email gets the signature messed up.

Comment: On further inspection it almost seems like after the replies Outlook 2007 treats all elements in the signature like an image which can be moved around. Is there a way to make Outlook 2007 not do this?

Comment: So I'm making progress! I noticed a lot of my problems were caused by the align="left". I removed them as much as I could and even ended up removing one column. They are now next to each other. 

I have also fixed the problem with the huge amount of space between the brown line and the red bar. The solution was to make this 1 table.

Comment: Just one  problem remains: huge amount of space between each table. This is especially true for Gmail (when I send a mail with the signature to gmail and then reply to that mail it comes back to Outlook with these huge spaces). 
When I send it from Outlook to Outlook and reply back the spaces are acceptable so not really a problem anymore.